# Update inventory after transaction

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `inventory` (
  `id_product` INT(4) ZEROFILL NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `model` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `price_new` FLOAT DEFAULT '0',
  sell_price float,
  `condition1` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `launch_date` DATE NOT NULL,
  `stock` INT DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_product`));  
  
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `order` (
  `id_order` INT(4) ZEROFILL NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_customer` INT(6) ZEROFILL NOT NULL,
  `subtotal` FLOAT DEFAULT '0',
  `discount` float DEFAULT '0',
  `tax_rate` float DEFAULT '0.23',
  `total` float DEFAULT '0',
  `date` DATETIME DEFAULT NOW(),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_order`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_order_1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_customer`)
    REFERENCES `iSAVE`.`customer` (`id_customer`)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE CASCADE);

  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `transaction` (
  `id_transaction` INT(4) ZEROFILL NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `id_order`INT(4) ZEROFILL NOT NULL,
  `status` char(20) default 'Not completed',
  FOREIGN KEY (`id_order`) REFERENCES `iSAVE`.`order` (`id_order`)
);

  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `order_item` (
  `id_order_item` INT(4) ZEROFILL NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `id_product` INT(4) ZEROFILL NOT NULL,
  `id_order` INT(4) ZEROFILL NOT NULL,
  `quantity` INT DEFAULT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (`id_product`) REFERENCES `iSAVE`.`inventory` (`id_product`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`id_order`) REFERENCES `iSAVE`.`order` (`id_order`)
);
```

I have those tables and my objective is after i update transactions to completed it goes to my inventory table and update the stock. The items that it should update are the items that i choose in order items.
For now i have this peace of code but its not working ...

```
delimiter $
create trigger update_stock
after update on `transaction`
for each row
begin
    if new.`status` = 'Completed' THEN
        update inventory
        set inventory.stock = inventory.stock - new.quantity
        where inventory.id_product = new.id_product;
    end if;
End $$
delimiter ;
```

Edited trigger:

```
delimiter $$
CREATE TRIGGER trigg1 after update on `transaction` for each row
BEGIN
UPDATE `inventory`
SET stock = (SELECT stock - new.quantity FROM order_item WHERE order_item.id_product = inventory.id_product limit 1);
end $$
delimiter ;
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on "its not working"? Are you getting an error? The wrong result?

Comment: i mean, that trigger was working when i had the satus on the order table. But the guys that im helping wanted it on other table called transactions. i add the table and now its not working. I update the status and doenst works.

Comment: `transaction` doesn't have a `quantity` column, so `new.quantity` can't work now...

Comment: My objective is update the the transaction table to completed and all the items that are connected with that same order id it goes to the inventory and updates the stock

Comment: So how can i do that ? @Mureinik

Comment: Or is even possible? or i need to add column id_product and quantity on transaction to make it wordk?

Comment: Just to observe that it's fantastically unlikely that a column called price would be FLOAT; it's why DECIMAL was invented

Comment: @Strawberry Thx i will update it

Comment: your trigger query should not run because new.quantity is not part of the table transaction

Comment: I updated my trigger and its running, my problem now its that is updating all the time just the 1 row on inventory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to need an extra `join` to get the quantity from `order_item`:

```
update inventory i join
       order_item oi
       using (id_product)
    set i.stock = i.stock - oi.quantity
    where oi.id_order = new.id_order;
```

Comment: But i still have a problem, every time i do this it duplicates the enteries, for example: if it is 2 it takes 4 from the stock, if it is 1 it takes 2 from the stock. But that only happens when my order has more then 1 order_item, if it only has 1 order_item doesnt duplicate if it has it duplicates.

Comment: @rubenferr . . . That would suggest that you have duplicates in one of the tables.  This query should only be updating the product in the stock with the product from `order_item`.  If there are two `order_item` rows for two different products, they should be updated separately.

Comment: There is no way to be able to make them at the same time?